# Отсроченное выполнение кода через перерисовку

Tags: delphi

Чтобы правильно и однозначно сформулировать вопрос начну с примера.

Есть MDI-приложение, и в нем две дочерние формы. На одной форме контролы для редактирования данных, на второй - для просмотра. Данные на формах разные, но логически взаимосвязаны. Пользовательские изменения на первой форме должны обновить данные на второй до актуального состояния. Операция обновления данных второй формы достаточно тяжелая и важна только тогда, когда эта форма находится перед глазами пользователя. То-есть, возможны две ситуации. Первая: формы развернуты рядом друг с дружкой, и обновлять данные второй нужно в реальном времени. Вторая: формы развернуты одна над другой, и обновить информацию второй имеет смысл только тогда, когда пользователь на нее переключится.

Для того чтобы реализовать такой механизм обновления, я соорудил велосипед на основе системной перерисовки окон. Суть его в том, что отправленное сообщение `WM_PAINT` доходит до окна-приемника только тогда, когда оно находится в области видимости, или тогда, когда оно появится в этой самой области видимости. Через `TForm.Invalidate` отправил сигнал к обновлению, а через `TForm.OnPaint` своевременно отработал само обновление.

Все работает классно, своевременно и без нареканий. Но когда таких взаимосвязей становится очень много, код превращается в кашу, а его сопровождение в - ад. Приходится держать кучу флаговых переменных, колбеков и другого мусора. Логически разные куски кода смешиваются в одной процедуре, и это не очень хорошо.

Вопрос: существуют ли какие-то стандартные механизмы для того чтобы делать подобные вещи "грамотно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безотносительно конкретного случая с двумя mdi-формами и wm_paint использую такую систему:

Для реализации какого-то сложного функционала создаю синглтон класса (называю его TFooManager), привязываю его к главной форме. В менеджере выполняется вся бизнес-логика, в том числе в отдельных потоках, обычно менеджер инкапсулирует в себе сложные структуры данных (коллекции, иерархию коллекций если нужно) со своей логикой.

А в форме(ах) идет лишь отображение/редактирование данных, обработчики событий в менеджере используются для обновления необходимой информации. При таком подходе в формах может быть все, что угодно в плане обработки визуальной части и своевременность обновления данных целиком лежит на плечах менеджера.

Еще такой нюанс. Используем DevEx, там есть замечательные virtual компоненты, которые можно использовать для отстраивания разнообразных структур в виде деревьев, гридов... Т.е. на основании структуры, созданной внутри менеджера пишется необходимый CustomDataSource (с каждой новой версией dev'ов писать приходится все меньше), по которому в формах отображаются данные. Этот datasource объявляется как публичное свойство менеджера, привязывается в главной или любой другой форме к визуальным компонентам, в менеджере к визуальным компонентам привязки нет, более того этих компонент вообще может не быть...

Могу сказать точно, что поддержка такого подхода не вызывает никаких проблем. Передавал в дальнейшую поддержку несколько таких реализаций.

По поводу низкоуровневого обновления формы вплоть до WM_PAINT дело пока не доходило.

ЗЫ Сорри за оффтопик :)

Comment: Пример с 2-я формами я привел для того чтобы понятнее сформулировать ситуацию. В форме можно сделать обработчик `WM_PAINT`. Но ведь `WM_PAINT`-ом можно бросить в любой `TWinControl`. И чаще подобные вещи нужно делать не для целых форм, а именно для отдельных контролов. И тут все усложняется тем, что нужно делать наследника. Например, есть сворачиваемый TImage, в который выводится эскиз. И читать этот эскиз из базы нужно только если контрол в области видимости.

То-есть, в основе такого менеджера отложенного выполнения должен лежать хук на перехват `WM_PAINT`-ов отправленных любому контролу.

Comment: Немного непонятно. WM_PAINT вызыается на любой чих - на перекрытие окна, на проведение над контролом мышкой и т.д. И обработчик для wm_paint, ясное дело, не должен читать что-либо из базы. Если данные изменились, нужно эскиз сформировать и уже после того как сформирован вызывать Invalidate. ИМХО, вычислять нужно ли брать эскиз из базы при изменениях в зависимости от того показывается Image или нет - плохая идея. Пусть эскиз берется из базы при изменениях, т.е. всегда когда нужен, например в отдельном потоке, а показывается или нет пусть image сам решит (видим он или нет)...

Comment: В отличии от остальных системных сообщений у `WM_PAINT` есть отличительная особенность. Если окно "на поверхности", система сразу передает сообщение оконной процедуре, а та делает перерисовку. Если скрыто - система ждет момента, когда все окно или какая-то его часть появится на экране, и только тогда передает ему `WM_PAINT`.

Этим можно воспользоваться. На вызывающей стороне устанавливается флаг `NeedUpdate` и отправляется `WM_PAINT`, принимающая строна проверяет установлен ли флаг, если установен, то сбрасывает,  загружает обновленные данные из базы и отдает управление процедуре перерисовки.

Comment: Таким образом, загрузка обновленных данных будет делаться только если это действительно необходимо.

Зачем лишний раз грузить из базы инфу, которую никто не увидит?

Comment: Но получается, что актуальностью данных (каких-либо) управляет видимость окна. Причинно-следственная связь обратная какая-то. Не вполне представляю вашу структуру хранения/расчетов, и согласен, что лишний раз дергать базу или делать холостые расчеты не стоит... Просто использование обработчика и для wm_paint и для обновления данных - смешение визуальной части и данных, надо семантически их разделить: отрисовка отдельно, получение данных отдельно.

Comment: Да флаг тут помогает, просто он относится к расчетам,  а не отображению. Отображение всегда одно и то же - отобразить какую-то картинку, а какую именно - старую или вновь полученную с точки зрения самого image, неважно. В принципе про это в ответе и писал.

Comment: > Но получается, что актуальностью данных управляет видимость окна.

А что в этом плохого? Данные не вычисляются (не загружаются) пока они не понадобятся. В некоторых динамических ЯП это [есть из коробки][1].

> ...использование обработчика и для wm_paint и для обновления данных...

Согласен, криво, но другого более универсального способа реализовать ленивые вычисления пока для себя не нашел. Да, собственно, если он существует, это и есть суть вопроса :)

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F